# Blender Fluid Drip Down Screen

Tags: fluid-simulation

Today, marks the beginning of my foray into the world of Blender and for my first project, I am interested in creating a fluid animation similar to that of liquid dripping down the screen.

I've recently asked [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/89778/blood-dripping-down-screen-effect/89786#89786) question which focuses a bit more on programming but I am looking into creating an effect similar to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YDzesiC0b7g)
that I can apply to a web page. I'm assuming that the background would have to be transparent so that the effect runs seamlessly over the page. Is there a way to have an array of preset animations with their own parameters that I would then be able to pick using some variable from my JavaScript? The effect would be started by a button press on my webpage.

Any ideas on how I could get started?

Comment: I read that you would like to change the viscosity, etc... Could you clarify what kind of output are you expecting from the fluid simulation? A video with alpha or something "more complex" for furher interaction?

Comment: Is there a way to have an array of different parameters so that every time the button is clicked, the rate at which the drips occur changes as well as the form of the drip? I can have for example, 3 preset drip animations with their own parameters and some variable deciding which one to pick. I'm expecting a basic video with alpha. The interaction I'm guessing would come solely from JavaScript.

Comment: Well if you wanted to do this in Blender, I would create a plane of glass, make it the same ratio as the frame, then parent it. Use the quick fluid and use the honey preset to have the fluid run down the plane of glass. Then play with the settings and repeat more times for different results.  This might be a little involved for someone new to Blender (unless you have 3d  experience). Have you thought of filming this with a real camera dripping chocolate down a window pane then changing the color in post?

Comment: I am all for doing this in Blender, just know that your getting into intermediate stuff and dealing with simulations is taxing on your computer. (I dont know your specs) If you want to do in Blender then research this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74686/how-to-create-clear-plastic-cycles and fluid sims.

Comment: I'm not sure my computer would be able to handle it honestly. I have a 2013 MacBook Pro Retina. Actually, my professor mentioned the same thing to me about just filming it on my own. Blender is probably overkill for this but at some point, would be fun to explore.