# How to create a semi transparent plastic shader?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, photorealism

I'd like to create a semi transparent plastic cycles material to match the material from this reference:

[image]

[image]

*My current node setup*

[image] 

*First rendering*

Any suggestion or help on that topic, what's missing and what I should add to get that plastic material look is appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: try adding thickness to your object and blending in either SSS or translucency

Comment: @Sazerac i added the thickness but its not working perfect as i need with the reference image

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74686/how-to-create-clear-plastic-cycles

Comment: @Mentalist can you plz send me the file with material. Im weak in material nodes hard to find all the nodes.

Comment: @atek This answer may be super helpful for you: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74686/how-to-create-clear-plastic-cycles

Comment: @atek No, but here's a tip: The nodes labeled things like "Multiply" in the screen shot are just Math nodes, so search "Math" to find them. The other ones with custom labels are Value nodes. Color nodes can be found by searching "RGB". With that knowledge you should be able to find everything you need.

Comment: @Mentalist if u send me the material i can learn what in the detail inside the nodes. Thanks

Comment: @atek I don't have the material already made. And I'm not going to do your work for you, because I'm plenty busy with my own projects. If you take initiative and use the screen shot as your guide, and you will learn what you want to know.

Comment: @Mentalist As i said before im weak in material. I want to know where the small geometry node came from. When i add the geometry node it give bunch of options.

Comment: @atek The small Geometry node you see is actually a regular Geometry node, but its other options have been hidden. If you select a node and press Ctrl H all sockets except the connected ones will be hidden. Pressing Ctrl H again switches it back to showing all sockets. Good luck! :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are elements of Refraction, Glossy, and Subsurface scattering in there so how about something like this :

[image: material]

This produces the following :

[image: result]

Vary the Mix factors, roughness and Subsurface scale to get the desired effect. Don't forget to have something in the scene to reflect/refract - eg, world environment texture and/or patterned surface, and suitable lighting, etc. Also, bevel any edges and ensure to add thickness.

Comment: will not getting that reference image effect and looks dark

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would do it like this (I know it's not the best you can get, but...well): 
[image: Material and result]

Maybe someone will give you some better suggestions...
Surely you can change the Factor of the Mix Shader, where I used 0.25, or leave it out.

Hope, I could help you (and sorry for my probably bad english)

Comment: Thanks for replying well its not that perfect what i need with the reference image