# Creating a colored translucent material for Plastic/PVC roll

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

I'm trying to make a material that closely resembles the below photograph (ignore the hue)

[image: blue PVC roll]

As you can see, my results below arent all that great, Whilst I'm okay(ish) at the modelling side, I'm useless when it comes to materials and in this instance I've hit a brick wall!

[image: PVC roll attempt]

[image: current node setup]

Any advice on the correct material setup would be really much appreciated! Please feel free to explain like you would to a five year old!

Comment: Try this node setup: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74686/how-to-create-clear-plastic-cycles/74709#74709

Comment: If what you're trying to achieve is the "ghost image" of all the inner stripes of tape, maybe increasing Transparency and Transmission Bounces in the "Light Paths" rendering settings could help?