# Translucent vinyl plastic material

Tags: materials, node-editor

I am trying to make a material similar to this unanswered post: [Creating a colored translucent material for Plastic/PVC roll](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90138/creating-a-colored-translucent-material-for-plastic-pvc-roll)

I tried the suggested methods and was unsatisfied with the results. I am most interested in recreating the effect that occurs at the edges of the material.

Below are two screenshots of my current setup that is giving the 'best' results, but is unreal as I use two materials for the one object.
[image: overview of setup]
[image: edges material]
Top left in the image editor is my reference image of the desired material look. 
Bottom left is my super basic node set ups for the face material. the other image shows my edge material.
Right is the plastic strip rotated 45º to show the edges backlit by a spot light 50W.
I placed a Suzanne behind to test the material transparency.
I am using a HDRi environment texture and a power 1 sun lamp to also light the scene.

Does anyone have any ideas how to make the material look more like the reference image? Ideally, using one material? I can use either eevee or cycles for this project.

Comment: Hey :). Have you tried the linked thread? https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/74686/

Comment: Hi yes, i have. I originally used that and then modified it to achieve the results above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: A simple glass table]

This is the setup I use for glasses, producing results such as the one above. It works by rendering the material as regular glass, except for lightrays that bounce too much (that is, more than three times), in which case it gets rendered as a simple green, transparent material. The `Volume Absorption` node is there to make sure the effect still happens when the sheet of glass is viewed from the side.

You can adjust it to your own needs by substituting the `Glass BSDF` node for the one(s) you've so far been using and tweaking the colours to your liking.

[image: Node tree]

You can check this and many other tricks for rendering glass-like materials in Vilem Duha's Blender conference, [Everything you wanted to know about rendering Glass not only with Cycles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sv2wqwsvx-8).

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful!