# Plastic bottle material

Tags: texturing

I want to make bottle as this one, but i cant find anyting like that. What is node material for that? I need transparent plastic material
[image]

Comment: What specifically are you struggling with?

Comment: Is it your question about using Glass Shader?

Comment: It looks like you are searching for something like this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74686/how-to-create-clear-plastic-cycles
Maybe you can try this material and change it the way you want

Comment: In Principled shader, I think that you can get a very nice approximation with transmission at 1 and roughness way down.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using 2.8, I found that the principled shader is very easy to set up for this provided you make use of an environment texture in the world shader.[image]