# Polyethylene (plastic bags) cloth settings?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I need to make plastic bags, can't find suitable physics settings, docs and tutorials are not helping. The main thing I need is believable cloth physics for animation. The bag should deform like the real life bag would due to the air resistance when the force throws it and the whrinkles should be rougher, well you know, how a plastic bag looks.

Cloth settings:
[image: screenshot of simulation and settings]
Shader:
[image: screenshot and material]

[Here's](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_2msOTTUIIvqUyoJKHICuO6Lla1dsbdX/view?usp=share_link) my blend file with the plastic bag and some force fields if you need it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to BSE! You can improve your chances to get an answer if you add a screenshot to your question (I just did that for you, since I had the blend file open), and briefly write about what you tried and where the difficulties are. This way your question can also help future readers who have the same or a similar problem. And it saves the readers time to find out if the question is relevant for them. Cheers!

Comment: @Blunder thanks!

Comment: do you need it simulated for animation or is it just an image (shapekey)?

Comment: @Blunder for animation

Comment: [Here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74686/how-to-create-clear-plastic-cycles) is a plastic shader that looks similar to what you want. if you add a Math node with Add +0.5 between the Layer and the Mix node (in Transmission) you can make the plastic a little more opaque.

Comment: @Blunder thank you, this one has much better translucency for onesided mesh

Comment: your link doesn't work...

Comment: @Chris yes, sorry, I updated the link