# Rough transparent plastic material with fake hollow inside

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, transparency

is there a shader that for transparent plastic that simulates a hollow inside, as described in [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74686/how-to-create-clear-plastic-cycles/74709?noredirect=1#comment413686_74709) answer, but whose roughness is also adjustable?
Using that node setup increasing the density value gives a somewhat rougher plastic but it looks a bit weird and I do not think that this is the correct way to do it

[image]

The problem is that using a Glass shader requires the mesh to have an inside and that would be quite hazel to the ad and increase render times drastically. OS I require a material that uses the same approach as in the linked question but with a roughness slider

Thanks for your help

Comment: hello, maybe show a picture of what you want

Comment: A picture of the look I want to achieve? I have added one

Comment: What kind of shape are you using it on - is it simple like a cube, or more complex with curves and nooks?

Comment: I have added a picture, hopefully, it is clearer now.

Comment: Yes, if I want to render the transparent material realistically, build an inside, it will drive up render times and would also increase the poly count. I could try just using a cube as the "inside" but that would still not help with the render times

Comment: I see. I'll look into it. Do you have objects inside your main object that you want to be able to see  through the "shell", and if so, do they need to be refracted perfectly, or just " close enough?

Comment: Just good enough is all I need, and yes I have bullets inside the magazine. Just like in the image.
Thanks for looking into it

Comment: Hello :). Geometry doesn't increase rendertimes. Slow shaders and lightbounces increase rendertimes. In this case, it won't be faster since lightbounces will be the same.

Comment: Yes and if I would do it the physically correct way that would be the case

Comment: @Phönix64 just a small trick: If you use the Incoming vector as the normal of a Refraction shader, you don't need to solidify the mesh, and you can use it's roughness.

Comment: Okay thanks will keep this in minde

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this - it might not be perfect, and may take some tinkering, but you can adjust the clarity/rougness through the Transparency Mix, the Roughness of the Glossy Shader, and the IOR if the Fresnel - between the 3 you should be able to find a mix that comes close. I added a bit of a Noise Texture to some Bump, to give it that "slightly bumpy plastic look" (and I mean *very* slightly - I mixed the noise texture .999 percent with white first), and I also colored/darkened the  glossy and diffuse colors to match the photo. The "magazine" is a flattened stretched cube (6 sides):

[image: Trans]

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly :)