# Making a clear plastic like material

Tags: materials

Ive been having some experiments with textures and other things lately, and ive been trying to get a result similar to this. of course I have tried a lot of things and since I am relatively new to this it didnt turn out so well. [image: from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imbIsNAvUpM&ab_channel=Polyfjord]

If there would be no easy way around trying to do something like this, from older questions ([How to create clear plastic? (Cycles)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74686/how-to-create-clear-plastic-cycles)) it would be nice to know how to make this one. Nodes are included on this but in the newer versions of Blender, some of the nodes are not available. [image]

Comment: Feel free to add a link to the old question. -- About the plastic shader of the old question, all nodes are still there in newer Blender versions (2.8+) => https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRxtf.jpg - The red nodes at the top left are *Value* nodes,  the color nodes below are called *RGB*, and the blue ones are *Math* nodes. In the side panel of the *Shader Editor* (key N), you can give the nodes a custom label. And Ctrl+H hides/reveals unused node sockets (or use the context menu).

Comment: Thanks, think im just really bad at lighting stuff since the product was much lighter than the picture and the reflections arent too great but thats my own problem

Comment: @nerdpants In the reference you posted (1st pic) there are two materials : a clear transparent glass and an opaque difuse blue material. The second pic is, I guess your attempt to reproducing it but you just used one material which is semitransmissive and blue. That's why it doesn't match.

Comment: well...if no one answers here...you can still go to polyfjords site, become a patron and ask him for help (if he didn't provide the blend file)

Comment: The shader for the legs and the body of this "spider bot" looks like a simple glass shader to me. Add a *Solidify* modifier to the cube/body. If you want to have the spheres a bit rough like plastic you can use a *Noise Texture* node, and a *Bump* node. The camera of this reference image has a lot of *Depth of Field*, so it's quite blurred. Here a quick try: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgcAz.jpg

Comment: @Blunder: damn...that's good. would you mind sharing the blend file?

Comment: Gotta agree with Chris my small brain couldn’t make that and it looks really simple a blend file would be cool

Answer (score 1):

The shader for the legs and the body of this "spider bot" looks like a simple glass shader to me. Plexiglass or acryl maybe?

To mimic the reference, add a *Solidify* and a *Bevel* modifier to the body (cube). The legs only need a *Bevel* modifier because they don't look hollow. Then use the *Principled BSDF* with *Transmission* set to `1` and lower the *Roughness* to make the glass clear.

If you want to have the spheres a bit rough like plastic you can use a *Noise Texture* node, and a *Bump* node.

The camera of this reference image has a lot of *Depth of Field*, so it's quite blurred. You can activate this in the camera settings. Lower the *F-Stop* value to control the bokeh effect.

For the lighting, try an HDRI with half strength and an *Area* light for example. In the example, the *forest.exr* is used that comes with Blender. It's located in the Blender directory *blender/<version>/datafiles/studiolights/world*.

Here is a quick try (Cycles):

[image: render test1]

[image]

Comment: great, thank you!!