# How to achieve a look similar to the plastic (or environment) in the example image

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I would like to achieve the following material look (I'm OK with the frosted effect):

[image: example material]

I've tried all sorts of things, like messing around with different materials, environments, etc. This material even in low light has an amplifying effect, especially for light shining on it.

My biggest issue is getting rid of the refraction:

[image: refraction issue]

[image]

Comment: Can you explain the function of the lines in the image?

Comment: Yes. The red lines indicate the problematic are. I tried to create a glass-like material, but as you can see on the real picture it looks completely different. This material is transparent, but where the cutout section it behaves very differently than other materials I've seen. Even at low light it amplifies the effect. I'm trying to get a same or similar effect as it is on the second image.

Comment: Have you tried [this plastic shader](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/74709/107598) yet? I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but when you replace the blue color with white/grey you get something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gqVi.jpg or https://i.stack.imgur.com/42mjg.jpg (depends on the light/HDRI)

Comment: No. But I will do. Looks lot better. What is the hdri you used?

Answer (score 0):

A part of the problem is **duplicate vertices**. By using *Mesh* → *Cleanup* → *Merge by Distance* in Edit Mode, I was able to get rid of 9563 vertices.

I then **beveled the edges** of the problematic area.
I used another HDR environment map*, as your file didn't contain the one you used. This is the result I got (all 512 passes):

[image: Resulting preview render]

The cutaway edges now seem to have the same amount of reflection as the adjacent geometry.

---

<sup>* Pearson Historic Hangar Closed, from [here](https://zenodo.org/record/1245790).</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the tip to clean up the model. But despite it, the problematic area still persists. You can try any HDR it will have the same effect. The cutout in the object will refract as it should in a normal glass object. My whole objective is how to circumvent that? I would like it to behave differently like a standard material as this isn't. Some specific plastic for which I could find a decent material setup.